# How to initialize a UIView subclass loaded from a xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

There are countless answers on how to subclass UIView, but none of them seem to help me.

I have a UIView Subclass

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DarkSeparatorUIView : UIView

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
#import "DarkSeparatorUIView.h"

@implementation DarkSeparatorUIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    // Do something
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    // Do something
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

In a separate xib I am creating a UIView and marking its class as "DarkSeparatorUIView". I expect that when the view loads that initWithCoder would be called, but it's not. Am I missing something?

Edit: I've tried awakeFromNib and it doesn't work, as well.

Edit2: This works in a fresh project, but not in my current project. I don't know what is different?

Comment: how about `awakeFromNib`

Comment: Yah same thing :x I should have posted that I tried that, too.

Comment: Is there some other thing I need to do to make the other xib recognize DarkSeparatorUIView?

Comment: so looks like you are not creating `DarkSeparatorUIView` from nib

Comment: "I expect that when the view loads that initWithCoder would be called, but it's not" - Show the code you think is supposed to load the view from the nib, please.

Comment: There is no code, it's in interface builder -- I though that by setting a UIView's class name to be DarkSeparatorUIView, that it would run DarkSeparatorUIView's initWithCoder.

Comment: I just tried what I'm trying in a new project and things work fine. I have no idea why this isn't working in my current project.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code
  self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DarkSeparatorUIView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
  return self;
}
```

make sure your xib named `DarkSeparatorUIView.xib`

Comment: Are you suggesting adding that to DarkSeparatorUIView.m? The problem is initWithFrame is never called.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that when I created DarkSeparatorUIView, I didn't include it in all of my build targets. If you didn't do this when you created the file, you can click on the file in Project Navigator, then select the File Navigator and select the targets you want the file to be available for.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has created a category on `NSBundle` declared in [UINibloading.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html). It adds the method `loadNibNamed:owner:options` to `NSBundle`, which makes it pretty easy to load a nib from a bundle.

I have created a category on `UIView` for this purpose. It defines a single method:

```
+(instancetype)viewFromNib
```

Include this category in the header of your custom `UIView` subclass to enable loading it from a nib using this one liner:

```
MyView *view = [MyView viewFromNib];
```

I've put the category in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/kaspermunck/1afd3ca724076244a40e), but the code loading the nib goes like this:

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil];

id view = nil;
for (id object in bundle) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        view = object;
    }
}
```